# Are all key codes cross-platform

Tags: keyboard

Pretty much every keyboard works on Windows, Macintosh and GNU/Linux the same.
I found this [Virtual Key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731.aspx) list.
Where do these key codes come from and how can I prove they are cross-platform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the key codes are **platform dependent**. 
They come from the **API** (application programming interface) of the current operating system.

For WinAPI you can find them [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx), for MacOS in [one of the header file](https://forums.sketchup.com/clicks/track?url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fphracker%2FMacOSX-SDKs%2Fblob%2Fmaster%2FMacOSX10.6.sdk%2FSystem%2FLibrary%2FFrameworks%2FCarbon.framework%2FVersions%2FA%2FFrameworks%2FHIToolbox.framework%2FVersions%2FA%2FHeaders%2FEvents.h&post_id=84322&topic_id=23540).

The firmware (driver) "translates" the keystrokes into the properly VirtualCodes dependent on the current OS. This is a kind of "mapping" to abstract the physical devices (keyboards) from the software layer (operating system).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so what makes a keyboard cross-platform? Is it the firmware that must be written for more os?

Comment: Exactly, the firmware (driver) "translates" the keystrokes into the properly VirtualCodes dependent on the current OS. This is a kind of "mapping" to abstract the physical devises from the software layer so to say.